# Featured product with multiple possible product types?

Tags: php, database, symfony

I have 3 different entities that all need to go into a table of featured products/entites/whatever. The problem is that the featured product can be of type entityA, entityB, or entityC. How do I model this and make symfony2 form for it? What would be the best approach?

Let's say for example it was a motor vehicle dealership that needed to select featured products but the product could be a "Motorbike", a "Car" or "Truck" (all of these are three classes with 3 tables storing their data).

I can think of maybe a table with nullable foreign keys that are one to many, and only enable one to be not-null but this doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 0):

Lol completely misunderstood the question sorry for that.

Anyway, I think the same strategy goes for what you're actually asking.

Table 'featured_products' object_ID FOREIGN KEY on 'objects'.'ID'

```
object_ID
1
2
3
```

Table 'objects' This will only hold your object ID's

```
ID (AI)
1
2
3
```

Table 'cars': object_ID FOREIGN KEY on 'objects'.'ID' (NO Auto Increment!)

```
object_ID | name
1         | Ferrari
2         | Duckatti
```

Table 'trucks': object_ID FOREIGN KEY on 'objects'.'ID' (NO Auto Increment!)

```
object_ID | name
3         | Monster truck
```

This setup would mean you'd have to change some code as well. As you have to insert a NULL value into objects and use the insert_ID with your cars, trucks etc.

I have never actually tried this. But you MIGHT have succes using the following query.

```
SELECT
   truck.name, car.name
FROM
   objects
LEFT JOIN trucks ON trucks.object_ID=objects.ID
LEFT JOIN cars ON cars.object_ID=objects.ID
WHERE objects.ID IN((SELECT * FROM featured_products))
GROUP BY objects.ID
```

Comment: Problem here is you'd have to perform 3 seperate queries or find another way (e.g. an enum or sth) of determining which object_ID belongs to what class... There must be a better way. See query in my post, maybe it works.

Comment: I don't like the "no auto increment", sounds like a minefield to me :/. Also I'm using symfony2 with doctrine, it's best for it to have auto increment id

Comment: Why is this best for your framework? It's not a minefield, if you forget to get the object Id it simply won't insert. Easy to see. The AI comes from another table, no difference.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood your answer, using an object table is a good idea. But how about a unique identifier in the entity tables? I'm thinking UUID but it doesn't really need to be universally unique, just across the one database...what sounds better?

Comment: I don't know what your security requirements are. I for one woulnd't care if someone would 'guess' his way into a car object...